Has right-wing politics on guns made it more or less impossible to reliably protect public figures?
Both assassination attempts on Trump used long-range weapons.
Right-wing politicians and the Supreme Court have legalized gun enhancements like bump stocks that allow a semi-automatic rifle with a bump stock to fire between 400 and 800 rounds per minute, similar to the rate of fire of a machine gun.
If private citizens can temporarily create a warzone anywhere in America - how can any public figure be reliably protected?

Protecting an important, highly visible and recognizable public official is difficult whether the public has access to a modified semi-automatic weapon or a single bullet, bolt-action rifle (or a concealed knife or poison or any number of other things that can be used to deadly effect). President John F. Kennedy was assassinated with a basic bolt-action rifle.

Arguably the issues in the middle para are more relevant to mass shootings than to single-target political assassinations. Nobody got off 400 rounds at Trump yet.

Military snipers don't use machine guns when they shoot enemy combatants at ranges exceeding a kilometer or more.  They use bolt action rifles that are legal in most jurisdictions on Earth.

I suppose one can complain about the 'collateral damage' in the 1st attempt on Trump though, being more like a mini mass shooting.

You totally, totally, misread how opposed bump stocks are to sniping.  LOL.  But besides that, you don't need a surfeit of weapons, most of the guns you'd use for this would have been just as available 20 years ago as now, to someone wanting to acquire them.  What's changed is how much the Secret Service have to spread their resources.  And that is due to both sides' increased stridency and demonization of the other.  That said, they need to cut the BS and just protect the heck out of Trump till the election.  End of story.

@Ryan_L "They use bolt action rifles that are legal in most jurisdictions on Earth." Bolt action rifle is something like a hunting rifle? I couldn't get one here unless I made through a special hunting learning program but I guess (shooting game at large distances means precision aiming) they would be suitable.

@ItalianPhilosopher "That said, they need to cut the BS and just protect the heck out of Trump till the election." It's also the copycat effect, once somebody does something horrible, others with the same idea also come out of hiding. But the secret service should be now know where to look and be able to protect all candidates.

It's worth noting that the attempts on Trump were the first assassination attempts on a US president or presidential candidate since John Hinckley shot Reagan 40 years ago, so evidently it's not that impossible.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution While it is true that in other parts of the world those types of guns are harder to get in the US they are not in the discussion of types of guns to ban/restrict other then simple background checks and waiting periods.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution Yes, a bolt action rifle is like a hunting rifle.  I don't believe Thomas Crooks Matthews had a criminal record, so he likely would have been able to sign up for that hunting license you mention.  The point being it could have happened in any jurisdiction that doesn't magically perfectly enforce a complete ban on all guns.  And even then as we saw with Shinzo Abe, even that might not be enough.

A question asking why the Secret Service is struggling to protect Trump adequately would be entirely on topic. Tying that failure to right wing politics on gun control is entirely misleading (and I support gun control myself).

"secret Service" is not a genie you invoke to protect what you want to protect.  It is a system of armed personnel, surveillance. threat assessment etc.  the sacredness of unlimited gun availability to private citizens advocated by Republicans has made the "secret service" impotent -@ItalianPhilosopher  Although white males are the overwhelming source of assassination threats, white males moving around carrying high-powered rifles are considered a-ok by most people.

It may sound a bit cynical, but a competent assassin needs only one shot, and even a competent security team often cannot prevent the first long-distance shot. The difference between a scoped bolt-action rifle, a scoped semiautomatic, and an actual assault rifle matters when the assassin misses, or when there are multiple random targets. Consider that the British Army issued semi-automatics rather than full automatics for a very long time -- they wanted aimed shots rather than spray and pray from their soldiers.
The availability of firearms in the United States means that murderers with limited means can get their hands onto firearms on short notice. In countries like the United Kingdom (with much stricter weapons laws than the US) and Germany (with somewhat stricter weapons laws), such people get knives and kill with those.
There are estimates that in the US there are 1.2 firearms per civilian, in England and Wales (UK) there are 0.046, while Germany has 0.20. But those numbers-per-person are misleading. It is not that one in five Germans owns a gun, it is a much smaller percentage who go through the mandatory training and testing and licensing and then typically own more than one gun. Net result, gun crimes happen, either by criminals who are sufficiently well organized to buy an illegal gun or by those with access to legal ones. But typical terrorist acts use a knife, or a truck, to kill many random victims.
Coming back to assassinations and assassination attempts rather than terror or amok cases, these do happen in Germany, both with firearms (Wolfgang Schäuble, Walter Lübcke) and with knives (Oskar Lafontaine, Henriette Reker).
Summarized, legalized bump stocks in particular and semiautomatic rifles in general add one more concern for the security team, but restricting them will not fully resolve the problem.

For the record, I believe that stricter gun laws in the US would save many victims of more or less random violence, e.g. because they turned into the wrong entrance or because they tailgated a road-rage-prone driver, and victims of domestic violence or suicides.

I like the answer up until the conclusion where "but restricting them will not resolve the problem." Is asking for too much. Just because something isn't the full solution but maybe only part of it doesn't mean it's useless and not worth doing. If restricting them would only alleviate the problem to some extent it would already be worth considering.

I like the answer, but I concur with the comment by NoDataDumpNoContribution: both of the attempts against Trump were carried by the type of people that wouldn't get a license in a saner country than the USA. Sure, in Germany two people of very similar profiles managed to strike at politicians using knives, but that's just because in Germany, being much more safer, politicians usually walk around without bodyguards.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution, I've added a few words to qualify my answer. But I stil think that a determined assassin would be able to get an illegal rifle.

@Rekesoft, I'm not the guy to go into seedy bars and look for illegal weapons, but I believe that paying five or ten times list price will get one a rifle or handgun without the papers. There are plenty of people who could not afford that, but also plenty wgo could.

@o.m. In many countries in the EU, it's not that easy. Just like buying cocaine, it's not only that you have to pay a hundred times more than its producing price, is that you have to know someone who sells it. With drugs, it's relatively easy, but you don't bump into shady people offering AK47 for sale in the outskirts of a pub or disco. You must have contact with gangs or terrorist organizations. Almost anyone owning an illegal weapon here had also served some time in jail already - prison is a great place to know gun sellers. But someone without antecedents wouldn't know where to look for.

@Rekesoft, of course I don't know the ratio of would-be murderers who failed to find a gun and gave up, but the Lübcke assassin and the Munich 2016 killer got them.

@o.m. the Lübcke murderer was part of a local shooting club. He was barred form owing fire arms due to the State and Federal Consitutional Protection Agencies having running flies on him. When they needed to throw out the files due to lack of activity, he sued the local government for still denying him a gun permit. Since his cases where no longer running, it was deemed that the city must give him a permit. This is how he came into legal firearm posession once more.

@SMSTJ, Ernst also had access to an illegal submachine gun, I thought, and according to Wikipedia the source of the murder weapon is unclear. But a legal firearms card would have helped with ammo and training opportunities.
